# Excel - Creating a two-way connection between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master Excel workbook and a couple of child workbooks that I want to feed into the master. I want to create a two way relationship between the two, meaning if I change something in one it changes into the other. I currently have a PowerQuery system so the data from the child workbooks feeds into the master but if I change something in the master it doesn't move into the child workbooks.

I can create a two way relationship using VBA between ranges in the same worksheet, is there a way to do so between different worksheets?

Thanks

Comment: Between two workbooks is not really that different from between two ranges on the same sheet, as long as both workbooks are open.

Comment: It sounds like you need [MSAccess](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/access)